# Unable to send to a recipient : c# exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtp, smtpclient

**Introduction**

I am working on application module which suppose to send more than 1000 emails to users on list....

**Problem**

the code which is responsible of sending emails works fine for first 100 email but then throws an exception on this function,

> smtp.Send(mail);
>
> I been trying to figure out whats wrong, i have tried several
>   techniques(like creating delay in sending emails, i.e: chunks of 50
>   emails per minute) but when count reaches about 100 email,,,, i
>   experiences this exception....

**Code**

```
m.From = new MailAddress("abcs@gmail.com", "abc");
                m.To.Add(new MailAddress(to, ""));
                m.Subject = subject;
                m.IsBodyHtml = true;

                var fromAddress = m.From.Address.ToString();

                var toAddress = to;
                const string fromPassword = "*****";
                //string body = "From: " + message + "\n";
                //body = message;
                var smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
                {
                    smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                    smtp.Port = 587;
                    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                    smtp.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                    smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress, fromPassword);
                    // smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress, fromPassword);
                    smtp.Timeout = 200000;
                }
                smtp.Send(m);
```

**Exception**

```
System.Net.Mail.SmtpFailedRecipientsException was caught
      HResult=-2146233088
      Message=Unable to send to a recipient.
      Source=System
      FailedRecipient=<abcs@gmail.com>
      StackTrace:
           at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
           at FlexiAnalysisLib.Common.MailHelper.AnalysisEmailViaAlternateView(String to, String subject, MailMessage m) in c:\beta development\FlexiAnalysisLib\Common\MailHelper.cs:line 553
      InnerException: System.Net.Mail.SmtpFailedRecipientException
           HResult=-2146233088
           Message=Insufficient system storage. The server response was: 4.5.3 Your message has too many recipients. For more information regarding
           FailedRecipient=<abcs@gmail.com>
```

> If anyone have idea about the problem, please help...

**Any kind of help or reference will be appreciated....
Thanks for your time**

Comment: _"Insufficient system storage. The server response was: 4.5.3 **Your message has too many recipients.**"_

Comment: @cubrr thanks for reply, well if we divide into 50,50 chunks or 10, 10 chunks then it will also throw exception after 100 combined emails sent ..... or may be i didn't get your point

Comment: This is a limit imposed by whatever email service you're using. https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22839

Comment: @cubrr yes indeed it is great help, i couldn't find it, thanks for help and please post it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a limit imposed by whatever email service you're using.

Google has a support page regarding this error which I think reveals a bit about why this limit exists: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22839

> **Message bounced due to sending limit**
>
> In an effort to fight spam and prevent abuse, Google will temporarily
>   disable your account if you send messages to more than 500 recipients
>   or if you send a large number of undeliverable messages. If you use a
>   POP or IMAP client (for example: Microsoft Outlook or Apple Mail), you
>   may only send a message to 100 people at a time. Your account should
>   be re-enabled within 24 hours.
>
> If you communicate with the same group of people on a regular basis,
>   you might be interested in Google Groups.
>
> If you send a large number of undeliverable messages, we suggest
>   verifying your contacts' email addresses. It's also important that
>   everyone you are sending mail to is willing to receive it.
>
> [Learn more](http://www.google.com/mail/help/bulk_mail.html) about best practices for sending a large amount of mail
>   through Gmail.